# esp-idf : I can't include mdebtls directory in a component

Tags: esp32, esp-idf

On esp32, using esp-idf, I built a module called webSocket.c/.h .
it includes

```
#include "esp32/sha.h"
```

As this module is generic, I want to put it in a component. I moved it to
"components/webSocket" directory and added a CMakeLists.txt file like this:

```
FILE(GLOB cFiles *.c)

set(
    COMPONENT_SRCS 
    ${cFiles}
)

set(COMPONENT_ADD_INCLUDEDIRS 
       "."
  )
  
register_component()
```

From this point, the module does not compile anymore because the above included file is unreachable.

This module is part of esp-idf framework, or more accurately, part of mbedtls lib which is embedded in esp-idf framework.

I tried all these path without success:

```
mbedtls/port/include/esp32/sha.h
port/include/esp32/sha.h
include/esp32/sha.h
esp32/sha.h
sha.h
```

None is successfull, how should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added

```
set(COMPONENT_REQUIRES mbedtls)
```

to CMakeLists did the trick.